# Postgresql - Minor version upgrade 9.3.5 to 9.3.6 on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, replication, installation

I am two servers: A & B. My master database is running on A and the version is 9.3.5. It's replica is running on B and the version is 9.3.6. I am trying to use B as UPSTREAM slave, and trying to start another database (on different port) which would be replica of B.
So the desired setup is like this: 
A:5432(master) -> B:5432(slave-upstream) -> A:5433(slave-downstream)

When I try to start A:5433(slave-downstream), it says:

```
FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host "5.6.7.8", user "replicator", SSL on
        FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host "5.6.7.8", user "replicator", SSL off
```

I've following entries on B:

```
host    all             all             5.6.7.8/32       md5
host    replication     all             5.6.7.8/32       md5
```

I am suspecing the problem might be due to the difference of versions? If it's the case, how can I upgrade postgresql on A to 9.3.6?

Or anyother help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your log on server A is being shared by the two databases (master of A and the slave of B).

It looks like you have set `ssl = on` in your master's `postgresql.conf` file and have set `ssl = off` in your slave(B). You should either set `ssl` to `on` on all servers or none.

PostgreSQL doesn't usually have a problem replicating across minor versions

Comment: Thanks for your help.

You are right that server A is being shared by the two databases but log files are being maintained separately. The slave database which is having issues in starting was created using initdb, and I am trying to start it with following command:

/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_ctl -D slave2 -l slave2.logfile start

The errors and being generated in slave2.logfile.

I've also verified the ssl thing and it seems to be correct as well.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the latest contents of all 3 log files after trying to start all 3 servers in the order 1.Master 2.slave1 3.slave2

Comment: Also is 'slave2' the correct path of your data diractory ? try using the full path eg:  -D /home/peter/slave2 .Where is your pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf located ?

Comment: This time I've used full path while starting slave2.

Here are the logs.
Master:
2015-03-10 15:04:31 PKT LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2015-03-10 15:04:31 PKT LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2015-03-10 15:04:31 PKT LOG:  incomplete startup packet

Comment: Slave1:
2015-03-10 15:23:54 PKT LOG:  entering standby mode
2015-03-10 15:23:54 PKT LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 0/83DFB48
2015-03-10 15:23:54 PKT LOG:  record with zero length at 0/83DFB48
2015-03-10 15:23:54 PKT LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
2015-03-10 15:23:54 PKT LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 0/8000000 on timeline 1
2015-03-10 15:23:54 PKT LOG:  redo starts at 0/83DFB48
2015-03-10 15:23:54 PKT LOG:  incomplete startup packet

Comment: Slave2:
FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host "104.236.134.54", user "replicator", SSL on
        FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host "104.236.134.54", user "replicator", SSL off

Comment: First try and get replication working between primary and slave 1 ; Try doing a basebackup of primary on slave1 using : pg_basebackup -X stream -h <ip-addr of primary> -D <data-directory> -U replicator -v -P  ,and then try starting slave1 database.

Comment: I believe it's working already. I've checked it by running queries on both master and slave1 and I am getting same results. pg_basebackup was also done already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21806/discussion-between-clyde-dcruz-and-user2436428).

Comment: You can vote up a comment if you have found it helpful 